# Forward all arguments passed to the `[` subset method to another object in R

Tags: r, r-s4

In R, I have an S4 class that "wraps" around a vector. I want to forward many of the normal S3 and S4 methods on this class to its `vec` slot, which contains the vector. However I'm having particular trouble with the `[` method, because of its special properties.  **Edit: I want to forward all arguments to `[` including `i`, `j`, `drop` etc to this inner vector, exactly as they are passed to the outer wrapper object**.

Here's a simple example of my code and what I've tried. Firstly, we start by defining this simple class and instantiating it:

```
> Foo = setClass("Foo", slots=c(vec = "numeric"))
> foo = Foo(vec=c(1, 2, 3))
> foo
An object of class "Foo"
Slot "vec":
[1] 1 2 3
```

All good so far, next we try to forward all arguments to `[` using the normal `...` dots:

```
> setMethod("[", signature=c(x="Foo"), function(x, ...){
+   print(list(...))
+   x@vec[...]
+ })
> foo[2]
list()
[1] 1 2 3
```

Clearly this doesn't work because it's not subsetting the vector at all. But not only that, the print statement shows that `...` are not capturing anything, even though `i=2` is being passed here. So I give up on using `...`.

Next I try explicitly using `i` and `j`:

```
> setMethod("[", signature=c(x="Foo"), function(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE){
+   x@vec[i, j, drop=drop]
+ })
> foo[2]
Error in x@vec[i, j, drop = drop] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

This doesn't work because I'm always passing in `j`, but R doesn't have a mechanism to selectively pass in arguments, so I'm a bit stuck here.

Next I try `match.call`:

```
> setMethod("[", signature=c(x="Foo"), function(x, ...){
+   call = as.list(match.call())
+   fun = call[[1]]
+   str(fun)
+   args = call[-1]
+   str(args)
+   do.call(fun, args)
+ })
> foo[2]
 symbol [
List of 2
 $ x: symbol foo
 $ i: num 2
Error in do.call(fun, args) : 
  'what' must be a function or character string
```

This is interesting, because it proves that `match.call` *does* capture extra arguments where `...` did not, but because `x` and `[` are captured as symbols and not as their real values, it's doesn't work this easily, and it's not clear how to resolve them.

How then can I forward all arguments passed to the `[` method to another object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of these issues are understood with a careful reading of `?setMethod`. I'll address your suggestions one by one, then add some of my own.

#### 1)

```r
setMethod("[", signature = c(x = "Foo"), 
          function(x, ...) { 
              print(list(...))
              x@vec[...]
          })
```

The formal arguments of the method do not match those of the generic function.  `setMethod` corrects them automatically, without warning (sigh).  Hence your *actual* method looks like this:

```r
getMethod("[", signature = c(x = "Foo"))
```

```
Method Definition:

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) 
{
    print(list(...))
    x@vec[...]
}

Signatures:
        x    
target  "Foo"
defined "Foo"
```

When we call `foo[2]`, we find that `x` matches `foo`, `i` matches `2`, and `...` matches nothing.  Hence `list(...)` is empty and `x@vec[...]` evaluates to `x@vec`.

#### 2)

```r
setMethod("[", signature = c(x = "Foo"), 
          function(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) {
              x@vec[i, j, drop = drop]
          })
```

The formal arguments of this method are fine, but you are indexing a vector as an array, which is an error.  You could ignore everything except `i` and simply return `x@vec[i]`, but there are still traps there (e.g., `i` could be missing).

#### 3)

```r
setMethod("[", signature = c(x = "Foo"), 
          function(x, ...) {
              call <- as.list(match.call())
              fun <- call[[1]]
              str(fun)
              args <- call[-1]
              str(args)
              do.call(fun, args)
          })
```

This one is wrong because (again) the formal arguments don't match those of the generic function, and for the reason you point out: `fun` is a symbol and `args` is a list of language objects (and maybe constants), which is not what `do.call` expects.  In any case, my opinion is that approaches based on `match.call` are too complicated and fragile.

#### How I would do it

Your definition of class `Foo` implies that `foo@vec` does not have a `dim` attribute.  It is always a numeric vector and never an array.

```r
Foo <- setClass("Foo", slots = c(vec = "numeric"))
foo.v <- Foo(vec = c(1, 2, 3))
foo.a <- Foo(vec = toeplitz(1:6))
## Error in validObject(.Object) : 
##   invalid class "Foo" object: invalid object for slot "vec" in class "Foo": got class "matrix", should be or extend class "numeric"
```

For this vector-like class `Foo`, I would define:

```r
setMethod("[", signature = c(x = "Foo", i = "ANY", j = "missing", drop = "missing"), 
          function(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) {
              if (nargs() > 2L)
                  stop("'x' of class Foo must be indexed as x[i]")
              else if (missing(i)) 
                  x@vec 
              else x@vec[i]
          })
```

This allows `x[]` or `x[i]` while prohibiting all of `x[drop=]`, `x[i, ]`, `x[i, , drop=]`, `x[i, j]`, and `x[i, j, drop=]`, which do not make sense for vector-like classes.

```r
foo.v[]
## [1] 1 2 3

foo.v[-2L]
## [1] 1 3

foo.v[1L, 1L, drop = FALSE]
## Error in foo.v[1L, 1L, drop = FALSE] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable
```

That error is a bit opaque.  It arises because our method is not dispatched for the signature in the call.  In practice, you would catch such cases with additional methods throwing more transparent errors.

Now let's consider a second class `Bar` similar to `Foo`, but whose `vec` slot can be a numeric vector or any array.

```r
setClassUnion("vectorOrArray", c("numeric", "array"))
Bar <- setClass("Bar", slots = c(vec = "vectorOrArray"))
bar.v <- Bar(vec = c(1, 2, 3))
bar.a <- Bar(vec = toeplitz(1:6))
```

For this vector- or array-like class `Bar`, I would define:

```r
setMethod("[", signature = c(x = "Bar", i = "ANY", j = "ANY", drop = "ANY"), 
          function(x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) {
              x <- x@vec
              callGeneric()
          })
```

where `callGeneric` implements what you were trying to implement with `match.call` and `eval` but in a more robust way.

```r
bar.v[]
## [1] 1 2 3

bar.v[-2L]
## [1] 1 3

bar.v[1L, 1L, drop = FALSE]
## Error in x[i = i, j = j, drop = drop] : incorrect number of dimensions

bar.a[1L, 1L, drop = FALSE]
##      [,1]
## [1,]    1
```

One could also define a method for `Foo` based on `callGeneric`, but for a purely vector-like class, the overhead of `callGeneric` might be a barrier.  The earlier method using just `nargs` and `missing` is much faster, and we often want methods for `[` to be tightly optimized, since they tend to be called in loops.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(foo.v[-2L], bar.v[-2L], times = 1000L)
## Unit: nanoseconds
##        expr   min    lq      mean median    uq   max neval
##  foo.v[-2L]   861  1148  1385.062   1271  1476 11808  1000
##  bar.v[-2L] 12382 14842 15671.225  15498 16031 77613  1000
```

#### Remark

The two `setMethod` calls above follow two good practices:

- The formal arguments of the methods match those of the generic function.
- The signatures specify the class of every formal argument, for clarity.  Omitted formal arguments get class `"ANY"`, without warning (sigh), which surprises many people new to S4.

Answer (score 0):

One working solution I've found, which I don't like very much, is to actually edit the `call`:

```
> setMethod("[", signature=c(x="Foo"), function(x, ...){
+   call = match.call()
+   # Edit the actual expression to make R think the user
+   # put `foo@vec` instead of `foo`
+   call[[2]] = quote(x@vec)
+   eval(call)
+ })
> foo[2]
[1] 2
> foo[3]
[1] 3
```